# Converting a String into two separate Strings

Tags: c#, string, substring

The string I have is in this format: "String1" String2

I need to separate out the string1 and string2 but can't seem to get this working using substring.

Has anyone got any advice please?

Thanks

Edit: Here is the code I am working with

```
int startIndex = testString.IndexOf("\"") + "\"".Length;
int endIndex = testString.IndexOf("\"");
string string1 = "";
string string2 = "";
if (endIndex > 0)
{
    string1 = testString.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
    string2 = testString.Substring(endIndex, testString.Length);
}
```

Comment: Please, add your code

Comment: So your string is literally a doulbe quote, some text, another double quote, and then more text?  If so you can just use `string.LastIndexOf` to find the second double quote and then `string.Substring`.  But without an example of what you tried it's hard to determine what part you're having problems with.

Comment: Sorry, added my code now.

Comment: @Heyley For the second call to `IndexOf` you need to pass the `startIndex` so it will start searching after the first double quote `int endIndex = testString.indexOf("\"", startIndex);`

Answer (score 2):

Following code will be helpful for you,

```
// Split('"') function split the string on the " character. So here we get an 
// array of: "String1" " String2"    
var strs= @"""String1"" String2".Split('"'); 

// foreach iterate over the resulted array to get each string
foreach(var str in strs){

   // Trim() remove the leading and trailing space from the string
   Console.WriteLine(str.Trim());
}
```

Comment: You can use an overload of `string.Split` to pass in `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to avoid the empty string before the first double quote.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a vague question but if I understand correctly, string one is in double inverted commas and string two is beside it?

If this indeed the case:

```
string combined = "\"string1\" string2";
string[] split = combined.Split(new[] { '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string str1 = split[0];
string str2 = split[1];
```

Comment: FYI to delimit double quotes in verbatim strings you use 2 double quotes `@"""String1"" String2"`

Comment: `string split` needs to be `string[] split`

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks for pointing that out, edited answer accordingly (no real advantage of using verbatim string in this instance).

Comment: also changing to `string[] split = combined.Split(new [] { '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` will allow you to just access `split[0]` and `split[1]`